# Basic jQuery Slider using HTML instead of PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, bjqs

I am attempting to create a SCORM file that uses the Basic jQuery Slider to allow the user to scroll through content for our online course. As of right now, the previous person who implemented this scroll feature did so in PHP, which doesn't seem to work with SCORM as it is a server based language. When the user scrolls through the pages, they auto-populate the individual pages.

```
<div id="my-slideshow">
   <ul class="bjqs">
      <li><?php include"webui-page1.php";?></li>
      <li><?php include"webui-page2.php";?></li>
      <li><?php include"webui-page3.php";?></li>
      <li><?php include"webui-page4.php";?></li>
      <li><?php include"webui-page5.php";?></li>
      <li><?php include"webui-page6.php";?></li>
      <li><?php include"webui-page7.php";?></li>
       <li><?php include"webui-page8.php";?></li>
        <li><?php include"webui-page9.php";?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have changed all of the PHP pages to .html format.

My question is, how do I include each individual page like before without using PHP? I'm sure its some kind of javascript but I haven't found a way yet.

Essentially I want this:

```
<div id="my-slideshow">
   <ul class="bjqs">
      <li> (*some kind of javascript)webui-page1.html</li>
```

Comment: You can't... PHP is a server side language, it executes *before* the result is sent to the browser. JavaScript is a client side language, it doesn't run until *after* all the content has been loaded. The closest you can come to is to use Ajax to load extra bits after the page has loaded.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.